# Problems reading long lines with Gedit

Tags: debugging, gedit

I'm using open source program Gedit as my favourite editor. However, when I tried to open a text file that contains many letters on one row, it opens the line really slow and letters overlaps each others (10.txt from the file http://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/mpera.zip). What are some good methods to find out where the bug is?

Comment: What does this have to do with C other than it's your editor?

Comment: I think Gedit is written in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want a way to wrap lines in gedit ?

You could try this plugin:

http://hartmann-it-design.de/gedit/TextWrap/index.html

Comment: I just like to know why kate shows files containing long rows correctly but gedit is unable to do that.

Comment: Because Gedit doesn't have a word wrap by default, apparently (otherwise there wouldn't a plugin for it, isn't it ?). http://askubuntu.com/questions/21326/can-i-toggle-word-wrapping-on-off-quickly-in-gedit